# Is 'she-woman' an acceptable counterpart of 'he-man'?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, offensive-language, connotation, neologisms

If this is, as it is, a real English example,

> I wanted to know what role his women played in persuading him that he was this incredible *he-man*.

can this

> I wanted to know what role her men played in persuading hers that she was this incredible *she-woman*.

be proper, too?

If *she-woman* is not proper, can anyone suggest a word that, in that phrase, would be more suitable?

Comment: *He-man* means "a strong, virile man". Would its supposed counterpart mean "a strong, virile(?!) woman" or "a woman who conforms to feminine stereotypes in the same way that a he-man conforms to the masculine stereotypes of strength and virility"?

Comment: @RahulNarain Is the opposite of a “strong manly man” a “weak girly girl”,
“strong manly girl”,
“weak manly girl”,
“strong girly man”,
“weak manly man”,
“weak girly man”, or a 
“strong girly girl”?

Comment: "She-woman" as an expression exists! M-W defines it as "a woman abundantly endowed with obviously or pronouncedly feminine qualities". But I would have said a she-woman is someone who was a bit butch looking.

Comment: If you'd grown up in the 80s, you'd know that the counterpart to He-Man was [She-Ra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-ra).  >_>

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe "she-woman" is going to be widely understood, and I believe you want "incredibly" not "incredible". The expression *he-man* is an idiom; the closest idiom I can think of is too "[girly-girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girly_girl)" (incredibly is a bit awkward there) or just incredibly "[feminine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feminine)".

Answer (score 1):

The important issue here is that *he-man* is an idiomatic expression. Often, idioms simply don't have a reasonable counterpart! As such, *she-woman* is a very awkward expression.

You may want to consider rewording your phrase, perhaps describing directly her virility and femininity, or comparing her to a traditional image of a woman --- perhaps you could call her [Venus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_%28mythology%29).

Answer (score 1):

As noted, *he-man* is an idiom, and I dare say a caricature. Those of us who grew up before feminism might remember this He-man Club from Little Rascals (or Spanky and Our Gang)

[image: Alfalfa and Spanky, the originators. See what a *he-man* Alfalfa is? (He's a cutie-pie!]

So, a caricature is what you're looking for in the opposite. You might want Rosie the Riveter

[image: Rosie the Riveter: She can do anything!]

or a Goddess

[image]

But please be assured that no woman who grew up in the 70s would be flattered by being asked *what role her men played in persuading hers that she was this incredible* *XX*, unless it is in a [Playboy Bunny interview](http://www.ultraswank.net/interview/confessions-of-a-playboy-bunny-%E2%80%93-part-1/).

The role *her **man** played in persuading her that she was this incredible* *XX* was that *he did not impart to her his **Y** chromosome*.

Answer (score 0):

I always considered "he-man" to be a reference to [He-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He-Man), defender of Eternia and the secrets of Castle Grayskull from the evil Skeletor.

[image: He-Man]

(image found from a Google image search for He-Man)

In using a similar reference to women, I'd probably call her a "[Wonder Woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman)", or a "[She-Ra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-ra)", if you're looking to stay "in-universe", as mentioned by [starwed](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/32999/starwed).

It's possible that this usage will depend on the listener's age and knowledge of characters originating from comic books and cartoons, but Wonder Woman is pretty widely known.